# trouble making a command starts automatically when the apps starts

Tags: python, broadcast, bacnet

so i'm trying to learn both python and BACnet using the BACpypes library, and i'm a little bit stuck right now.

I'm trying to make the "WhoIs-IAm" sample application to do an automatic "IAm" broadcast when launched but regarding my newbie skill i'm having trouble to build it.

So there's the sample.

```html
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
This application presents a 'console' prompt to the user asking for Who-Is and I-Am
commands which create the related APDUs, then lines up the coorresponding I-Am
for incoming traffic and prints out the contents.
"""

import sys

from bacpypes.debugging import bacpypes_debugging, ModuleLogger
from bacpypes.consolelogging import ConfigArgumentParser
from bacpypes.consolecmd import ConsoleCmd

from bacpypes.core import run

from bacpypes.pdu import Address, GlobalBroadcast
from bacpypes.app import LocalDeviceObject, BIPSimpleApplication

from bacpypes.apdu import WhoIsRequest, IAmRequest
from bacpypes.basetypes import ServicesSupported
from bacpypes.errors import DecodingError

# some debugging
_debug = 0
_log = ModuleLogger(globals())

# globals
this_device = None
this_application = None
this_console = None

#
#   WhoIsIAmApplication
#

class WhoIsIAmApplication(BIPSimpleApplication):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        if _debug: WhoIsIAmApplication._debug("__init__ %r", args)
        BIPSimpleApplication.__init__(self, *args)

        # keep track of requests to line up responses
        self._request = None

    def request(self, apdu):
        if _debug: WhoIsIAmApplication._debug("request %r", apdu)

        # save a copy of the request
        self._request = apdu

        # forward it along
        BIPSimpleApplication.request(self, apdu)

    def confirmation(self, apdu):
        if _debug: WhoIsIAmApplication._debug("confirmation %r", apdu)

        # forward it along
        BIPSimpleApplication.confirmation(self, apdu)

    def indication(self, apdu):
        if _debug: WhoIsIAmApplication._debug("indication %r", apdu)

        if (isinstance(self._request, WhoIsRequest)) and (isinstance(apdu, IAmRequest)):
            device_type, device_instance = apdu.iAmDeviceIdentifier
            if device_type != 'device':
                raise DecodingError, "invalid object type"

            if (self._request.deviceInstanceRangeLowLimit is not None) and \
                (device_instance < self._request.deviceInstanceRangeLowLimit):
                pass
            elif (self._request.deviceInstanceRangeHighLimit is not None) and \
                (device_instance > self._request.deviceInstanceRangeHighLimit):
                pass
            else:
                # print out the contents
                sys.stdout.write('pduSource = ' + repr(apdu.pduSource) + '\n')
                sys.stdout.write('iAmDeviceIdentifier = ' + str(apdu.iAmDeviceIdentifier) + '\n')
                sys.stdout.write('maxAPDULengthAccepted = ' + str(apdu.maxAPDULengthAccepted) + '\n')
                sys.stdout.write('segmentationSupported = ' + str(apdu.segmentationSupported) + '\n')
                sys.stdout.write('vendorID = ' + str(apdu.vendorID) + '\n')
                sys.stdout.flush()

        # forward it along
        BIPSimpleApplication.indication(self, apdu)

bacpypes_debugging(WhoIsIAmApplication)

#
#   WhoIsIAmConsoleCmd
#

class WhoIsIAmConsoleCmd(ConsoleCmd):

    def do_whois(self, args):
        """whois [ <addr>] [ <lolimit> <hilimit> ]"""
        args = args.split()
        if _debug: WhoIsIAmConsoleCmd._debug("do_whois %r", args)

        try:
            # build a request
            request = WhoIsRequest()
            if (len(args) == 1) or (len(args) == 3):
                request.pduDestination = Address(args[0])
                del args[0]
            else:
                request.pduDestination = GlobalBroadcast()

            if len(args) == 2:
                request.deviceInstanceRangeLowLimit = int(args[0])
                request.deviceInstanceRangeHighLimit = int(args[1])
            if _debug: WhoIsIAmConsoleCmd._debug("    - request: %r", request)

            # give it to the application
            this_application.request(request)

        except Exception, e:
            WhoIsIAmConsoleCmd._exception("exception: %r", e)

    def do_iam(self, args):
        """iam"""
        args = args.split()
        if _debug: WhoIsIAmConsoleCmd._debug("do_iam %r", args)

        try:
            # build a request
            request = IAmRequest()
            request.pduDestination = GlobalBroadcast()

            # set the parameters from the device object
            request.iAmDeviceIdentifier = this_device.objectIdentifier
            request.maxAPDULengthAccepted = this_device.maxApduLengthAccepted
            request.segmentationSupported = this_device.segmentationSupported
            request.vendorID = this_device.vendorIdentifier
            if _debug: WhoIsIAmConsoleCmd._debug("    - request: %r", request)

            # give it to the application
            this_application.request(request)

        except Exception, e:
            WhoIsIAmConsoleCmd._exception("exception: %r", e)

    def do_rtn(self, args):
        """rtn <addr> <net> ... """
        args = args.split()
        if _debug: WhoIsIAmConsoleCmd._debug("do_rtn %r", args)

        # safe to assume only one adapter
        adapter = this_application.nsap.adapters[0]
        if _debug: WhoIsIAmConsoleCmd._debug("    - adapter: %r", adapter)

        # provide the address and a list of network numbers
        router_address = Address(args[0])
        network_list = [int(arg) for arg in args[1:]]

        # pass along to the service access point
        this_application.nsap.add_router_references(adapter, router_address, network_list)

bacpypes_debugging(WhoIsIAmConsoleCmd)

#
#   __main__
#

try:
    # parse the command line arguments
    args = ConfigArgumentParser(description=__doc__).parse_args()

    if _debug: _log.debug("initialization")
    if _debug: _log.debug("    - args: %r", args)

    # make a device object
    this_device = LocalDeviceObject(
        objectName=args.ini.objectname,
        objectIdentifier=int(args.ini.objectidentifier),
        maxApduLengthAccepted=int(args.ini.maxapdulengthaccepted),
        segmentationSupported=args.ini.segmentationsupported,
        vendorIdentifier=int(args.ini.vendoridentifier),
        )

    # build a bit string that knows about the bit names
    pss = ServicesSupported()
    pss['whoIs'] = 1
    pss['iAm'] = 1
    pss['readProperty'] = 1
    pss['writeProperty'] = 1

    # set the property value to be just the bits
    this_device.protocolServicesSupported = pss.value

    # make a simple application
    this_application = WhoIsIAmApplication(this_device, args.ini.address)

    # get the services supported
    services_supported = this_application.get_services_supported()
    if _debug: _log.debug("    - services_supported: %r", services_supported)

    # let the device object know
    this_device.protocolServicesSupported = services_supported.value

    # make a console
    this_console = WhoIsIAmConsoleCmd()

    _log.debug("running")

    run()

except Exception, e:
    _log.exception("an error has occurred: %s", e)
finally:
    _log.debug("finally")
```

I just don't know how to call the do_iam so it starts automatically when the app launches.

Any help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After the line `this_console = WhoIsIAmConsoleCmd()`, can you write `this_console.do_iam('')`?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried this earlier and didn't worked...but i just figure it out ! the IP router is blocking the broadcast so when i just entered an adress it worked.

Comment: @B.Abd Yes, sometimes the router will restrict the broadcast. In that scenarios you can target the network with the broadcast ip. Using `ipaddress` module get the `broadcast_address` and pass it to pduDestination as `Address(broadcast_address)`. Then this request will target the devices on the network that communicate with this `broadcast_address`. BACpyes is expecting to release more of this kind functionalities in v0.18.0

Comment: @OwlyMoly Thank you for the answer even if i solved my issue 2 years ago lol it would help other people who are searching for more info. Edit to give even more info: the broadcast_address is the address of a BBMD that manages the broadcast "Bacnet Broadcast management Device", other devices will register to the BBMD which will broadcast the message on its subnetwork or send it to another BBMD if the broadcast is intended on another subnetwork.